# Windows 7 special folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is what I want to do.

Windows 7 installs from CD, DVD or USB drive.
Windows installation completes.
windows explorer opens to a specific folder based upon media used to install windows.

The below code is what I have so far.

```
timeout 10
msg * You need to install programs from this directory as appropriate to your needs
explorer %basefolder%\App Installs
```

Is there a Special folder that refers to the basefolder?  I know of %appdata% and %USERPROFILE% but do not know if there is one that can refer to the media used whether USB drive or DVD.

I know I can copy the App Installers to the computer and then run a batch file but the directory is quite large (>2GB) and would really slow down the installation.

Comment: Where is the script being run from?  The installation media, network drive, or locally on the machine?

Comment: locally.  I want this for stand alone systems.

Comment: You are not clear with what you do. You install windows from external device? If you try to deploy OS and wish to run commands, read about microsoft wds

Comment: I am creating a windows installation ISO that can be USB or DVD.  If I install from USB, I want it to open a specific folder on the USB drive once WPI completes.  If I install from DVD, I want it to open a specific folder on the DVD upon completion of WPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If running the script from the installation media, you can reference the media drive path by using `%~d0`.  Else, if running from a network drive or locally, you can scan each drive for a unique file or folder.

```
for %%A in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do if exist "%%~A:\unique_file.txt" echo Found my drive.
```

Answer (score 0):

This will launch the installer from the folder/usb/dvd and then explorer will open in the "\App Installs" folder on the same media.

The working directory will only change if you specifically leave the device that the installer was launched from.

```
installer.exe "to target folder"
explorer "\App Installs"
```